# Python doesn't delete every file/dir

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, shutil

I want to move the contents of the "temp" folder to the main folder which contains let's say for an example 2 folders and 1 file:

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. python.exe
```

In the `temp` folder I have EXACT same content. I want to first delete the content of the `main` folder and then move the content from the `temp` folder to the `main` folder which should be empty because I deleted all the files and folders, right?

The problem is `os.rmdir` and `os.remove` doesn't delete all the files... It deletes maybe 2 files out of 4 and 1 folder out of 2. I'm not getting any permission related errors I only get the shutil error saying that the destination path already exists (Becauase it wasn't deleted by `os.rmdir()` for some reason).:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Test/Desktop/test_folder/ftpdl.py", line 346, in run
    shutil.move(os.getcwd() + "\\temp\\" + f, os.getcwd())
  File "C:\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 564, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test_folder\Mono' already exists
```

My code looks like this:

```py
dircontents = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for file in dircontents:
    if file == os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + "\\" + file):
        if file != 'testfile.py' and file != 'logo.ico' and file != 'settings.xml' and file != 'settings_backup.xml':
            os.remove(os.getcwd() + "\\" + file)
            break
    if file == os.path.isdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + file):
        if file != 'temp':
            os.rmdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + file)
            break

newfiles = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\temp")
for f in newfiles:
    shutil.move(os.getcwd() + "\\temp\\" + f, os.getcwd())
```

The expected result is that all of the old content of the main folder gets deleted and the new content from the temp folder gets moved to the main folder but It's quite not working. I would say It's partially working.

Comment: `file == os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + "\\" + file)` is never true, because `file` is never `True` or `False`, but `os.path.isfile()` only ever returns a boolean.

Comment: Next, even if the `if` tests would ever be `True`, you used `break` and so cut the loop short. The remainder of filenames in `dircontents` is never processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
if file == os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + "\\" + file):
```

`isfile()` returns `True` or `False`, not a filename. You should just test the result of the call, not compare it with the filename.

There's also no need to prepend `os.getcwd()` -- relative pathnames are always interpreted relative to the current directory. Similarly, `os.listdir()` defaults to the current directory.

So it should be:

```
if os.path.isfile(file):
```

And you shouldn't have `break` -- that makes the loop stop after the first thing it removes.

And use `elif` for the second test, since the two cases are mutually exclusive.

```
dircontents = os.listdir()
for file in dircontents:
    if os.path.isfile(file) and file not in ['testfile.py', 'logo.ico', 'settings.xml', 'settings_backup.xml']:
        os.remove(file)
    elif os.path.isdir(file) and file != 'temp':
        os.rmdir(file)

newfiles = os.listdir("temp")
for f in newfiles:
    shutil.move("temp\\" + f, os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Well, it quite works... I changed this part:
`elif os.path.isdir(file):
        if file != 'temp':
            os.rmdir(file)
            break
`
to this because the directory I want to delete is not empty:
`elif os.path.isdir(file):
     if file != 'temp':
         shutil.rmtree(file, ignore_errors=True)
         break
`
Although, It doesn't delete everything and I don't even get any errors.

Comment: Any clue how to do it?

Comment: `break` still ends the loop, so you won't remove anything after removing the directory.

Comment: That's why you're not removing everything.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot about it. It works now perfectly.